# Django urls.py not found

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

Setting up the urls for a Django app called `OmniCloud_App`. Getting and error when accessing /OmniCloud_App/signup that the url is not found. here is the main urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  (r'^OmniCloud_App/$', include('OmniCloud_App.urls')),
  (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

which then includes OmniCloud_App/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('OmniCloud_App.views',
    (r'^', 'home'),
    (r'^signup/', 'signup'),
    (r'^(?P<User_id>\d+)/$', 'profile'),
    (r'^(?P<User_id>\d+)/social$', 'social'),
    (r'^(?P<User_id>\d+)/news$', 'news'),
    (r'^(?P<User_id>\d+)/email$', 'email'),
    (r'^(?P<User_id>\d+)/photos$', 'photos'),
)
```

so signup should go to the signup method in views.py:

```
def signup(request):
    return render_to_response('OmniCloud_App/Templates/OmniCloud/signup.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Any reason why this won't work? Here is the 404, which implies that it never got past the initial urls.py file, although visiting simply /OmniCloud_App/ renders the 'home' page correctly (which is also defined in the `include('OmniCloud_App.urls')`

[image: urls.py 404 page]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to remove the `$` from here

```
(r'^OmniCloud_App/$', include('OmniCloud_App.urls')),
```

so that it's:

```
(r'^OmniCloud_App/', include('OmniCloud_App.urls')),
```

The $ means end of string.

Comment: Ah very good. I had tried that but then it accepted /OmniCloud_App/* (any string) I also needed to add the $ after signups/